# Is there any php like array type in .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net

I am good at working with PHP arrays because it goes multidimensional like we can use the mixed array types in PHP like

```
Array["first_array"][0]=>1
                [1]=>"Rehmat"
 ["second_array"][0]=>1
                 [1]=>"asd"
```

Can we have these type of arrays ? in .net if yes please guide me

Comment: closest thing I can think of the Dictionary type or the Hashmap

Comment: The inner array looks like it should be an object with two values, not an array.

Comment: Create a proper object model instead of this horrible magic string based stuff.

Comment: @DarkBee but Dictionary doesnt store multi dimensional it works on key=>value

Comment: @HighCore haha thanx for the courtesy .. but the thing is php is loosely type we dont have to cast anything the variable takes what ever you give you must know it as you guys are professional

Comment: Your value can be another Object, meaning it can be an Array/Dictionary/Object

Comment: because my objective is to i have a navigation panel I have the code written in php for looping the navigation and creating html attributes.

Comment: @Servy made an answer with dictionary aproach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like you have an outer array that maps a string to an inner array, and the inner array maps an integer key to a value, where that value could be any type.  That can be represented like so:

```
Dictionary<string, object[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object[]>()
{
    {"first_array", new object[]{1, "Rehmat"}},
    {"second_array", new object[]{1, "asd"}},
}
```

This is of course a direct conversion; this solution is not particularly idiomatic in C#.

You should most likely have the value of the dictionary instead but a custom object:

```
public class Foo //TODO rename
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then have a dictionary mapping strings to those objects:

```
Dictionary<string, Foo> dictionary;
```